How does PhotosApp.exe know the sort order of the files in the Windows Explorer window it was opened from?
I have a folder containing photos and videos.
When I sort by name in Explorer, then open a file, then in the photo app hit right arrow, it correctly identifies the next file as shown in Explorer.
If I close the photos app, change the sort order to Date, and open a file, then hit next, it again correctly goes to the next file in the now-sorted-by-date explorer window.
If I have the same folder opened twice in explorer, sorted differently, then the photos app is still able to determine the correct ordering based on which explorer window I open the first photo in.
How does the photos app accomplish this?
Looking at the command line in task manager, I see
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2024.11070.1 -ServerName:App.AppXrsrmxw2kqfxg8qs234ywwm8hk94nw24k.mca
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2024.11070.1 /lnvokerPRAlD: App
C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe -Embedding
which doesn't reveal much.

How can I replicate this behaviour?
A demonstration I would be interested in would be something like
$target_dir = "C:\whatever"
loop {
  for each explorer window open {
    print top 5 file paths in explorer's sorted order
    print selected file paths
  }
  sleep 1 second
}

Can this be done with PowerShell?

It’s pretty trivial to look at the appropriate registry keys when you are the developer of Windows and the photo application. Without the source code to the application it might be difficult to answer this question

Don't know why command would reveal anything. The app is likely using some low level Windows APIs. Hints for what kind of can be found e.g. on SO - IFolderView2.
